# how to bootstrap p-value in ttest in Stata?

Tags: t-test, bootstrap, stata, p-value, skewness

Suppose I need to run `ttest bhar12=0` and the output comes as:

```
One-sample t test
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Variable |     Obs        Mean    Std. Err.   Std. Dev.   [95% Conf. Interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
  bhar12 |     124   -.0325875    .0751874    .8372516   -.1814163    .1162414
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mean = mean(bhar12)                                           t =  -0.4334
Ho: mean = 0                                     degrees of freedom =      123

    Ha: mean < 0                 Ha: mean != 0                 Ha: mean > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.3327         **Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.6655**          Pr(T > t) = 0.6673
```

If I knew the distribution for `bhar12` is positively skewed, how can I perform a `ttest` to get the **bootstrapped Pr(|T| > |t|) value**?

Comment: These data would have to be pretty badly skewed to appreciably change the large p-value returned by `ttest`.  Perhaps you are using this merely as an illustration and are looking for a general answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bs prefix like this:

`bs p=r(p), reps(1000): ttest bhar12=0`.

Note the warning about dropping observations that you might want to exclude (like those with missing values).

As an alternative, you might also want to consider Johnson's corrected $t$ test for skewed data. You can use `findit johnson` to locate and install it. This gives you the standard $t$ test output, Johnson's modified $t$ test (t1), and Chen's version of modified of Johnson's test (t2). t1 and t2 are usually very close unless the assymetry is great or the sample size is less than 10 (which is not the case for your sample).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  Do you think calculate bootstrapped p-value and compare it with the not bootstrapped p-value would be an appropriate way of checking whether the variable bhar12 suffers from potential skewness problem? Or in the cases where the not bootstrapped p-values are quite large, there is generally no need to bootstrap the p-value? And thanks for the johnson, learnt something new, t1 and t2 turned out to be the same.

Comment: Personally, I would just look at the distribution and use the old ocular test. If the data looks skewed, use the Johnson. When the data are skewed, then *one-sided* t tests can be badly off. I think that's less of an issue with *two-sided* tests, like you're doing here.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I think I am more clear about it now.